# Can not run redhat/ubi8 latest via docker run command

Tags: docker, redhat, redhat-ubi

I am trying to run redhat/ubi8.

```
docker pull redhat/ubi8
docker run redhat/ubi8
```

The `docker run` command returns with no output.

The `docker container list` command lists the container:

> 71b0897317aa   redhat/ubi8:latest     "/bin/bash"              21 minutes ago   Exited (0) 21 minutes ago             amazing_volhard

Trying to get the log with `docker logs amazing_volhard` gives no output.

**Some additional diagnostics facts:**

- The weirdest thing, I can successfully run this very image using Docker Desktop, via just clicking run. The running container seems to be working, however also **outputs zero line to the log**.
- I can also successfully run other linux images via command line `docker run` for example cassandra:latest, or `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started` all successfully writing to the log

**Question**

Although I understand redhat/ubi8 is a base image which's purpose to build my own custom images on it, still would like to understand, why I can not run it with `docker run` while I can run it via Docker Desktop GUI, and I also would like to understand why the log is empty for both the successfully started container, and the unsuccessfully started container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many base images, `redhat/ubi8` runs a shell by default (`/bin/bash` in this case, but it doesn't really matter).

If you run `bash` and standard input is closed, it exits immediately. You can see that same behavior if you run something like:

```
bash < /dev/null
```

Because you're executing `docker run` without specifying `-i`, that's exactly  what's happening here:

1. You run `docker run redhat/ubi8`
2. The `redhat/ubi8` image runs `/bin/bash`
3. `/bin/bash` sees that stdin is closed, so it exits

If you want to see different behavior, either add `-i` and `-t` to your command line:

```
docker run -it redhat/ubi8
```

Or run something other than a shell:

```
docker run redhat/ubi8 sleep inf
```

Comment: many thx, clear now..